# When was the last Ashwamedha yajna conducted?

Tags: history, yajna, ashwamedha

I have read at few sites that Pushyamitra Shunga (2nd century B.C.) had conducted two Ashwamedha yajnas. Did any king conduct Ashwamedha yagna after Pushyamitra ?

Comment: this is best suited on history.SE...

Comment: @YDS - It is related to history of Hinduism, which is within the scope of HSE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last king to perform the Aśvamedha yajña was the 18<sup>th</sup> century Rajput ruler [Sawai Jai Singh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jai_Singh_II).

In [History of Dharmaśāstra, Vol II Part II](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.57575/page/n545/mode/2up), P. V. Kane lists a few others:

> In Indian Antiquary vol. VIII. p. 273 (at p. 278) we find that a general, called Udayacandra, of Nandivarma Pallavamalla (about the 9th century A. D.) defeated Pṛthivīvyāghra, king of Niṣadha, who had accompanied the horse in his horse sacrifice.
>
> In Epigraphia Carnatica vol. X, Kolar No. 63, it is stated in an inscription of 757 A.D. that the Calukya emperor Pulakeśi was purified by his bath at an Aśvamedha.
>
> In the very ancient Nanaghat Inscription (Archaeological Survey of Western India Reports vol. V. pp. 60-61) an Andhra king is described as having performed the Rājasūya, two Aśvamedhas, Gargatrirātra, Gavāmayana and Aṅgirasām-ayana.
>
> In the first half of the 18<sup>th</sup> century Savai Jayasing, king
> of Amber, performed an Aśvamedha (vide Īśvaravilāsakāvya of
> Kṛṣṇa-kavi, D.C. Ms No. 273 of 1884-86 and Poona Orientalist, vol.
> II. pp.166-180).

Comment: excellent find !